# Gnuplot - How do not plot a piece of line for non-contiguous date/time

Tags: gnuplot, datetime-format

I'm trying to plot last 24 hours from datafile. This data file has
date/time and value

Below are the contents of `datafile.dat`:

```
2015-12-17-21:07:41,74.30
2015-12-17-21:08:41,74.10
2015-12-17-21:08:41,74.10
2015-12-30-21:08:41,79.10
2015-12-30-21:09:41,79.10
....
```

below gnuplot script

```
set datafile separator ","
set terminal png font arial 12 size 1000,600
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"
set format x "%d/%m\n%H:%Mh"
set xrange [ time(0) - 86400 : time(0) ]    # 86400 sec = 1 day 
set grid
set output "/data/weather/humidity.png"
plot "datafile.dat" using 1:2 with lines smooth bezier title ""
```

As I don't have data in the file for day 29, why does gnuplot draw a line from day 29 to day 30?
I don't have rows in the data file for day 29, and I'd like to not draw them.
If I don't have 24 hours of data in the the file, I would like to draw just what I have.

How can I do that?

Comment: How should gnuplot know, that a data point is missing?

Comment: Usually, to interrupt a line one would insert a point with an invalidate value like `NaN`. But probably you'll get problems with the smoothing, because `smooth bezier` plots a single bezier of order n-1through all n points.

Comment: Hi Christoph,

That is my problem. If I am in day 30 8:00AM and set xrange to last 24 hours gnuplot will draw line from day 29 8:00AM to day 30 8:00AM. I can not understand why day 29 is included if I do not have data for day 29. 

If my datafile has data for days, 30, 17, 16, 15... for me make sense gnuplot draw the line just from day 30 0:00AM to day 30 8:00AM. I know that is less than 24 hours but in fact I do not have continuously data in the last 24 hours, so why not gnuplot draw just what I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gnuplot has an option `set clip` which controls how lines connecting to points outside the given range are drawn: `set clip one`, which is the default, draws lines between two points if one of the points is in-range. The line is clipped at the plot border. `set clip two` would plot line parts even if both points are out-range, but the line goes through the plot area.

Use `unset clip` to plot only lines between points which are both in-range.

```
set datafile separator ","
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"
set format x "%d/%m\n%H:%Mh"
set xrange [ time(0) - 86400 : time(0) ]
unset clip
plot "datafile.dat" using 1:2 with lines title ""
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work properly with smoothing, because gnuplot first does the smoothing between all points (in-range and out-range), and then only applies the clipping rules. In order to have the smoothing handles properly you must filter the points before handling them to gnuplot, e.g. with awk:

```
set datafile separator ","
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"
set format x "%d/%m\n%H:%Mh"
set xrange [time(0) - 86400 : time(0)]

filter = '< awk -F, -v d="$(date -d''24 hours ago'' +''%F-%T'')" ''$1>=d'' datafile.dat'
plot filter using 1:2 with lines smooth bezier title ""
```

Note, that the comparison `$1 >= d` in awk is a string comparison, but that is fine for the time format you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As Christoph already mentioned, apparently `smooth` will smooth the data also outside the current plotting range. However, there is no need for awk or external tools, you can do it with gnuplot only (hence platform-independent).

Simply filter the data outside the range with gnuplot via:

```
myFilter(col,t) = t<t0 ?  NaN : column(col)
```

The script creates some random test data with some missing data gap. When plotting only a part of the range you will get the unwanted (and unexpected) smoothing with data outside the plotting range, although you set `unset clip`.

**Script:**

```
### smooth filtered data
reset session

myTimeFmt = "%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S"
set datafile separator ","

# create some random test data
set table $Data
    set samples 50
    SecPerDay = 3600*24
    t0 = time(0)
    y0 = 100  
    plot '+' u (sprintf("%s,%g", strftime(myTimeFmt,t0=t0-3600),y0=y0+rand(0)-0.5)) w table, \
         t0 = t0 - 3*SecPerDay, \
         '+' u (sprintf("%s,%g", strftime(myTimeFmt,t0=t0-3600),y0=y0+rand(0)-0.5)) w table
unset table

set format x "%b %d" timedate
set key out noautotitle
set grid x,y

N  = 3    # N last days
t1 = time(0)
t0 = t1 - N*SecPerDay

myFilter(col,t) = t<t0 ?  NaN : column(col)

set multiplot layout 3,1

    set title "full data range"
    plot $Data u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 w l ti "data", \
            '' u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 smooth bezier w l ti "smooth"
    
    set title "limited range with unwanted smoothing outside range"
    unset clip
    set xrange[t0:t1]
    plot $Data u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 w l ti "data", \
            '' u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 smooth bezier w l ti "smooth"

    set title "limited range with filter"
    set xrange[t0:t1]
    plot $Data u (t=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):(myFilter(2,t)) w l ti "data", \
            '' u (t=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):(myFilter(2,t)) smooth bezier w l ti "smooth"

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]